# Dumping strings out of executable

Tags: string, executable, dump

(To be honest, I don't know much about programming, please tell me if this is the wrong place to ask!)

My question is how to get a string dump like [this](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/58205a5fc0ee2f52ac169a31e5e3cb35/raw/6f841e99d1553e34887c0238cea69b8b2b7ab07a/wd2_crc32_dump.txt) out of an executable / dll. Everything I tried didn't get me a dump like the linked one with those hashes and the bit of help I got was not exactly helpful for someone like me... Which program should be used for this and how exactly do I have to do it?

I'd be grateful for every help I get!

Comment: is this what you are looking for ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999923/best-dll-symbols-dump-utility

Comment: Not quiet :/ Basically I search for a way to get those CRC32 hashes connected to their strings out of an exe / dll

Comment: do you already have a way on how to dump "the strings" out of the executables? if so, you then need to iterate on them line by line and compute the CRC32 hash using a programming/scripting language like python or bash. For instance in linux there is the command `crc32` that computes the crc32 hash for a file..

Comment: here's a small python script that computes crc32 for a file: https://gist.github.com/matteomattei/160c1198682e92f6f2a0